# GT 720M (Optimus) display driver setup - Crunchbang Waldorf/Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus, crunchbang

After installing Crunchbang 11 (based on Debian Wheezy) and booting up for the first time, I am forced into a shell as Xorg fails to start with `Fatal server error: no screens found`.

My laptop has an Optimus based GT 720M. Nouveau was automatically installed during setup, and appears to be picking up the GPU to some extent:

```
[  126.101860] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  126.101881] [drm] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: Detected an NVd0 generation card (0x0d7000a2)
[  126.105833] [drm] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: Checking PRAMIN for VBIOS
[  126.148715] [drm] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: ... BIOS signature not found
[  126.148718] [drm] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: Checking PROM for VBIOS
[  126.148786] [drm] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: ... BIOS signature not found
[  126.148788] [drm] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: Checking ACPI for VBIOS
[  126.148790] [drm] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: ... BIOS signature not found
[  126.148792] [drm] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: Checking PCIROM for VBIOS
[  126.148891] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: Invalid ROM contents
[  126.149875] [drm] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: ... BIOS signature not found
[  126.149876] [drm] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: No valid VBIOS image found
```

I have tried installing bumblebee and primus, though neither seemed to have helped. Optirun seems to fail recognising the second GPU (though this may be due to Xorg not running):

```
~$ optirun glxgears
[  625.400763] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)

[  625.400809] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 0a0c (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a03 (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP Thermal (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 12)
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1140 (rev a1)
```

/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Layout0"
    Option      "AutoAddDevices" "false"
    Option      "AutoAddGPU" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver      "nouveau"

#   If the X server does not automatically detect your VGA device,
#   you can manually set it here.
#   To get the BusID prop, run `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` and input the data
#   as you see in the commented example.
#   This Setting is needed on Ubuntu 13.04.
    BusID "PCI:04:00:0"

EndSection
```

It may be worth noting that it is a UEFI-based system.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off with nvidia proprietary driver and primus, just checked this fiddling with my ALT Linux based LiveCD on a Lenovo B570e booted in UEFI mode.

Newer laptops with optimus tend to have video outputs wired to intel GPU only, BTW.

Comment: Unfortunately, the latest nvidia package available on wheezy (304.88) is not compatible with my GPU. There seems to be a compatible version (331.38) in experimental, but I was having a bit of trouble getting it to install.